# How does skip and take works in linq

Tags: c#, linq

i have following Linq query . its works well but the thing that seems confusing is how does `skip()` and `take()` function working in linq.
here is my query

```
(from GRD in _tblAcademicYears.GetQueryable()
             where GRD.SchoolID == intSchoolID                 
             select new AcademicYearsModel
             {
                 AcademicYearID = GRD.AcademicYearID,
                 SchoolID = GRD.SchoolID,
                 AcademicYearName = GRD.AcademicYearName,
                 AcademicYearStart = GRD.AcademicYearStart,
                 AcademicYearEnd = GRD.AcademicYearEnd,
                 AcademicYearRemarks = GRD.AcademicYearRemarks,
                 IsActive = GRD.IsActive,
                 CreatedOn = GRD.CreatedOn,
                 CreatedBy = GRD.CreatedBy,
                 ModifiedOn = GRD.ModifiedOn,
                 ModifiedBy = GRD.ModifiedBy
             }
    ).Where(z => z.AcademicYearName.Contains(param.sSearch) || z.AcademicYearStart.ToString().Contains(param.sSearch)
    || z.AcademicYearEnd.ToString().Contains(param.sSearch) || z.AcademicYearRemarks.Contains(param.sSearch))
  .Skip(param.iDisplayStart).Take(param.iDisplayLength).ToList();
```

How this query will get record from data base .
will it get all record from database and then will apply `skip()` and `take()`.
or it will just get record that are with in limits of `skip()` and `take()`

Comment: It take records from the database as per your where query and keep it as queryable and then apply skip and take to the specific data

Comment: What happens is going to depend on the specifics of the query provider you're using, in addition to the specific query being performed.  Log the generated query to find out what's actually happening.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call .Take only, it will just translate to SQL: TOP N syntax

When you call .Skip and .Take together, it will generate at least 2 queries, by using ROWNUMBER to filter out.

So the short answer for your question is: No, it will not get all records from database. it will run a SQL to filter and select.

If you are curious, you can always use SQL profiler or just check the generated SQL in the debug mode.

Here is a simple MSDN article explains it
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb386988(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 2):

If you asking about LINQ to SQL, you can run a sql-profiler to get query, generated by linq provider.
But I can tell you, LINQ will get only records in limits `skip` and `take`, using [row_number](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734(v=sql.120).aspx) operator in SQL:

The query will be like this (skip 3 and take 3):

```
SELECT TOP (3) 
[Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
FROM ( 
    SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Extent1].[Name] ASC) AS [row_number]
    FROM [dbo].[tec_Stores] AS [Extent1]
)  AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[row_number] > 3
ORDER BY [Extent1].[Name] ASC
```

In LINQ to Entities it works different, depending on collection you use.

Comment: are you sure this works this, i use to think the linq skip and take works on only the querryable data?

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee linq2sql with mssql works like this, linq2object works different

Answer (score 1):

The source code of all Linq IEnumerable extensions can be found here:
[System.Linq.Enumerable](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs)

Here you can see how skip and take work